# How Can I Create A Service To Alphabetize A Comma Separated Text String?

Tags: itunes, text, metadata, sort

My understanding is that RegEx will not do this. What will?

My issue, specifically, is extremely messy iTunes genre tags. I would like to merge genre tags that have the same or similar comma separated values, and to merge those values in alphabetical order. I have found scripts that can do this with tab separated lists, but not comma separated strings. I have not been able to find any existing app (or script) that will allow me to merge, for instance:

'Rock, Indie, Soundtrack, Folk, Electronica, Experimental'

with

'Folktronica, Experimental, Soundtrack, Rock, Indie'

to result in

'Experimental, Folktronica, Indie, Rock, Soundtrack'

Another instance might be merging and alphabetizing the genre strings of tracks with classifications such as:

'Harmonica Blues, Electric Blues, Blues'

'Blues, Harmonica Blues, Electric, Harmonica'

'Harmonica, Blues, Electric Blues'

into

'Blues, Electric Blues, Harmonica Blues'

What's my best bet?

Comment: Please add a link to the script(s). The problem here is probably **not** the separator - it may be changed from `tab` or `;` to `,` inside the script - but the rules how to merge categories/genres...

Answer (score 1):

I found the/an answer by combining the information
here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23026003
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445211

The created service looks like this:

[image]

I will probably look into how to modify this to work on batches of tracks, which will be a little bit different since the text, itself, isn't, in that instance, specifically selected, but this works for now on a single track at a time basis.